# What is this prepositional phrase modifying?

Tags: commas

> A cabin stood at the end of the trail, on the edge of a mountain lake.

My analysis on what **"on the edge of a mountain lake"** modifies in this sentence is that it can modify **"a cabin"** or **"the trail"**.

Comment: Or the entire clause.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford then, you think it can be seen as modifying "the trail, a cabin, and the entire clause" ?

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: @JamesK I just brought it from this link https://www.quora.com/Can-prepositional-phrases-be-set-off-with-commas-as-non-restrictive-prepositional-phrases-please-provide-examples-as-well

Comment: No. I said *or*. It can modify *a cabin*, *the trail*, or *a cabin stood at the end of the trail*. (Which, as a noun, translates to *a cabin that stood at the end of a trail*. As opposed to a cabin that stood elsewhere.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I have two more questions. Q1) If **"the trail"** is substituted with **"it"** as in **"A cabin stood at the end of it"**, can **"on the edge of a mountain lake"** be regarded as modifying **"it"** ? Q2) If **"which is"** is included as in **"A cabin stood at the end of it, which was on the edge of a mountain lake"**, can **"which"** be regarded as modifying **"it"** ?

Comment: If one part of a sentence modifies a noun or noun phrase, then replacing the noun or noun phrase with a pronoun simply means that part of the sentence now modifies the pronoun. Substituting a pronoun might make the referent less clear, but it doesn't change the essential grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be either. But pragmatically we are more interested in the cabin, and it is more likely that a cabin is located on a lake than the path that leads to it.  It would be understood as implying that the cabin was by a lake.